# Can data.table assign-by-reference (mutate) preserve vector names

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a named vector of colors that I'm using to assign to a new column using `:=`, based on a column value. If I use a dplyr mutate, the result is different than a data.table style mutate. With dplyr, the vector names are preserved, whereas in data.table the names are lost.

Let me walk you through what I've figured out so far.

```
# first I make a named vector of colors
movieColors <- c("Aladdin" = "steelblue1",
                 "Beauty" = "gold1",
                 "Brave" = "darkorange1")
# lets create some dummy data
dt <- data.table::data.table(movie = c("Aladdin", "Beauty", "Brave"), 
                             movieNum = 1:3)

# I want a new column that tells me the color of each movie for each row
# a dplyr mutate
dt1 <- dplyr::mutate(.data = dt, 
                     movColor = movieColors[movie])
# a data.table mutate
dt2 <- dt[, movColor := movieColors[movie]]

# check the results and they look the same
dt1
dt2

# check that they are the same
dplyr::all_equal(dt1, dt2)
# they're not the same?

# the dplyr mutate is preserving the named vector
dt1$movColor
# the data.table mutate does not preserve the named vector
dt2$movColor
```

If you run it, you can see that `dt1`, the dplyr version, prints:

> ```
> Aladdin            Beauty         Brave 
> "steelblue1"       "gold1"        "darkorange1"
> ```

while the data.table version, `dt2` prints:

> ```
> [1] "steelblue1"   "gold1"        "darkorange1"
> ```

Why isn't data.table preserving the named vector? Is there a way to force it to do so?

Comment: This seems perhaps an XY problem.  There is no loss of information, because the names are available in a separate column (`movie`).  Any subsequent subsetting, ordering or grouping operations would be done in a more data.table fashion by using the column with the names, rather than a names attribute.  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878262/how-to-create-data-table-from-vector-with-named-values-and-keep-the-names) for cases where the names columndoes not already exist.

Comment: Thank you. I had a poorly constructed ggplot chain where I was trying to self-reference for a scale_fill_manual. I found a better way when I realized what problem I was having, but still wanted to know why the poorly constructed version only worked with dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dww pointed out, there is no specific need to keep the names in the movies column. While I do not know why {dplyr} supports this while {data.table} does not, you can use `data.table::setattr()` to achieve the same result.

```
# first I make a named vector of colors
movieColors <- c("Aladdin" = "steelblue1",
                 "Beauty" = "gold1",
                 "Brave" = "darkorange1")
# lets create some dummy data
dt <- data.table::data.table(movie = c("Aladdin", "Beauty", "Brave"), 
                             movieNum = 1:3)

# I want a new column that tells me the color of each movie for each row
# a dplyr mutate
dt1 <- dplyr::mutate(.data = dt, 
                     movColor = movieColors[movie])
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'tibble':
#>   method     from  
#>   format.tbl pillar
#>   print.tbl  pillar
# a data.table mutate
dt2 <- dt[, movColor := movieColors[movie]]



# size prior to adding names
object.size(dt2)
#> 2008 bytes

# add names to the movies column in place
data.table::setattr(dt2$movColor, "names", dt2$movie)

#size after adding names
object.size(dt2)
#> 2368 bytes



# check the results and they look the same
dt1
#>      movie movieNum    movColor
#> 1: Aladdin        1  steelblue1
#> 2:  Beauty        2       gold1
#> 3:   Brave        3 darkorange1
dt2
#>      movie movieNum    movColor
#> 1: Aladdin        1  steelblue1
#> 2:  Beauty        2       gold1
#> 3:   Brave        3 darkorange1

# check that they are the same
dplyr::all_equal(dt1, dt2)
#> [1] TRUE

# the dplyr mutate is preserving the named vector
dt1$movColor
#>       Aladdin        Beauty         Brave 
#>  "steelblue1"       "gold1" "darkorange1"
# the data.table mutate does now preserve the named vector
dt2$movColor
#>       Aladdin        Beauty         Brave 
#>  "steelblue1"       "gold1" "darkorange1"
```

As you see, I just use information that is already in the data.table. Consequently, the size of the object increases. Might be that this is also the answer to why data.table strips the `names` automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I had a poorly constructed ggplot chain where I was trying to self-reference for a scale_fill_manual. I found a better way when I realized what problem I was having, but still wanted to know why the poorly constructed version only worked with dplyr.